# Write spatial operations to PostGIS from QGIS or ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, qgis, python, postgis, postgresql

I need to write my spatial operations to a (new) postgis layer (as the data is to large for a shp file). Can this be done in the QGIS browser or from ArcGIS without SDE?

When you go (for example) --> vector--geoprocessing--clip or geometry--multipart to singlepart you can only save to a shp format eventhough the input data is from postgis.

I have tried the postgis manager and you can edit tables, import/export data but I can't see any way of writing the data to postgis directly.

I have qgis lisboa and postgis 2.5 as well as arcgis advanced (10.1) but not ArcSDE. If necessary a python solution is fine (maybe using @dimitris response in [Writing a plugin for Qgis using python to access PostGIS and write geometries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407/writing-a-plugin-for-qgis-using-python-to-access-postgis-and-write-geometries)

=== POSTGIS Attempt

I am new to Postgis. So as a test I have run the following from http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html

```
SELECT (ST_Dump("LowRez_HighHz".the_geom)).geom AS the_geom

FROM 
  public."LowRez_HighHz";
```

It runs with the following output

> Total query runtime: 68839 ms. 47591 rows retrieved.

and then I get an output but has it really removed all the multiparts? I doesn't look like it's writing.

So when I add the following

```
-- Break a compound curve into its constituent linestrings and circularstrings
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(a.geom), ST_HasArc(a.geom)
  FROM ( SELECT (ST_Dump(p_geom)).geom AS geom
         FROM (SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('COMPOUNDCURVE(CIRCULARSTRING(0 0, 1 1, 1 0),(1 0, 0 1))') AS p_geom) AS b
        ) AS a;
          st_asewkt          | st_hasarc
-----------------------------+----------
 CIRCULARSTRING(0 0,1 1,1 0) | t
 LINESTRING(1 0,0 1)         | f
```

I get

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "st_asewkt" LINE 11:
>   st_asewkt          | st_hasarc
>                          ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "st_asewkt" SQL state: 42601

How do I correct this?

The table details are

[image]

FROM http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_dump.snippet I also tried the following

```
SELECT "LowRez_HighHz", ST_Multi(ST_Collect(f.the_geom)) as singlegeom FROM (SELECT "LowRez_HighHz", (ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom As the_geom FROM "LowRez_HighHz" ) As f GROUP BY "LowRez_HighHz"
```

and I get

> ERROR:  out of memory DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 15183219.
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: out of memory SQL state: 53200 Detail: Failed on request of
>   size 15183219.

I have 16GB RAM and 1TB free space...what's happening?

**=== Testing Micha's input**

I can't seem to run the code in one go. I get

> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence
>   "lowrez_highhz_single_gid_seq" for serial column
>   "lowrez_highhz_single.gid" ERROR:  Table 'LowRez_HighHz_single' does
>   not occur in the search_path CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT
>   AddGeometryColumn('','', $1 , $2 , $3 , $4 , $5 )" PL/pgSQL function
>   "addgeometrycolumn" line 4 at SQL statement

But when I run

```
-- Create a new table
CREATE TABLE LowRez_HighHz_single (gid serial, Shape_Leng numeric, Shape_Area numeric);
```

It creates it as

> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence
>   "lowrez_highhz_single_gid_seq" for serial column
>   "lowrez_highhz_single.gid" Query returned successfully with no result
>   in 60 ms.

When I then comment out the first line and add

```
-- Make it a spatial table
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('LowRez_HighHz_single','geom',4283,'POLYGON',2);
```

I get

> ERROR:  Table 'LowRez_HighHz_single' does not occur in the search_path
>   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','', $1 , $2 , $3
>   , $4 , $5 )" PL/pgSQL function "addgeometrycolumn" line 4 at SQL
>   statement

What am I doing wrong? I also tried public."LowRez_HighHz_single"

=== Update on using all lower case.

I tried it but fails...might be because the table has mixed case currently.
[image]
the error code is

> ERROR: relation "lowrez_highhz" does not exist SQL state: 42P01
>   Character: 327

I also tried it on a dataset that is already all lowercase.
[image]

Comment: If data is too large for a shapefile (or for many other reasons) I usually write output to a file geodatabase.  If PostGIS is not a strict requirement maybe this workaround would work.

Comment: I do this to when using arcgis but qgis can't write to a fgdb either. I want to use postgis as in arcgis I have had many issues with even fgdb's once they got over 1GB and have had to split them into multiple parts (and then rejoin them) to process them effectively and am hoping that reading/writing to Postgis will eliminate some of these issues.

Comment: You could just move the original shapefiles into PostGIS and do the processing there. PostGIS has i.e. ST_Intersection for "clipping" and ST_Dump for multi to single part.

Comment: thanks @Micha I tried ST_Dump but it is giving me some errors. Please see my updated Question.

Comment: Loose all the CapitalLetters in the table name. Try: AddGeometyrColumn('lowrez_highhz_single',...).  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a sec. How did we get into CIRCULARSTRINGs? If I understand correctly you have a MULTIPOLYGON layer, LowRez_HighHz, which you want to break up (multipart to single part) into POLYGONs. That's what ST_Dump can do.

```
-- Create a new table
CREATE TABLE LowRez_HIghHz_single (gid serial, Shape_Leng numeric, Shape_Area numeric);
-- Make it a spatial table
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('lowrez_highhz_single','geom',4283,'POLYGON',2);
-- Use ST_Dump to insert new geometries
INSERT INTO lowrez_highhz_single(geom) SELECT (ST_Dump(lh.geom)).geom FROM lowrez_highhz AS lh;
```

As for the "Out of Memory" error, I can't seem to understand what you're trying to do. It seems you are breaking up the MULTI features and recombining them into a collection in one select??

Comment: -thanks for some clearly documented test code. I had some issues with it, please see the updated question. I didn't understand what the code from the postgis/bostongis support site did exactly as it wasn't clearly documented and I am a postgis baby.

Comment: Loose all the CapitalLetters in the table name. Try: AddGeometryColumn('lowrez_highhz_single',...). Sorry for the confusion. I also put these changes into the answer above.

Comment: -no luck. It still doesn't work. I have updated the question. best.

Comment: Two things to check: Can you drop that table and recreate (re-import) the shapefile, but using only lower case from the start?  Also make sure that the column named 'geom' is created (after AddGeometryColumn() ) and check what is in the geometry_columns table. i.e. SELECT * FROM geometry_columns. Be sure that the table is there with the correct geometry column name.